# Bedeutung von "so denn überhaupt eine stattfindet"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Vergreist Deutschland? Bricht die Zeit der kinderlosen Gesellschaft an? Droht die Rentenkatastrophe? Schrille Töne begleiten von jeher jede Debatte über Demografie -- **so denn überhaupt eine stattfindet**.

Was bedeutet der fettgedruckte Teil "so denn überhaupt eine stattfindet"? Eine direkte Übersetzung

> so because one takes place at all

macht für mich keinen Sinn. Ich kann auch keine besondere Bedeutung von "so denn" finden.

Comment: "so denn" simply means "if"...

Comment: @Gerhard Thanks. Could you provide a reference? For example I can't find it [here](http://www.dict.cc/?s=so+denn).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**So**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/so_obwohl_falls) als Konjunktion bedeutet hier "wenn" oder "falls". 
Das [**denn**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/denn_verstaerkende_Partikel) ist lediglich eine verstärkende Partikel.

Man könnte also z. B. auch schreiben:

> … wenn überhaupt eine [Diskussion] stattfindet.

Comment: Man sollte anmerken, dass es ohne das "denn" wohl nicht auf den ersten Blick zu verstehen wäre. " - so überhaupt eine stattfindet". Ich hätte gestutzt. "So" alleine ist sehr fixiert in seiner wie-Zeigewirkung, und die Formulierung zu selten. Der Kopf einen Moment braucht einen Moment um das von hinten vorzukramen.