# Subjunktion "so da" veraltet, aber noch verwendbar?

Tags: vocabulary, dictionary

Kann man die Subjunktion "so da" heutzutage noch verwenden? Also im Sinne von:

> Ich werde dies machen, so da die Bedingungen erfüllt sind.

So ähnliche wie der Eidesformelzusatz: "... , so wahr mir Gott helfe." Nur eben mit leicht anderer Bedeutung.

Comment: Würdest du das denn wie "so wahr mir Gott helfe" betonen, also mit Betonung auf dem "da"? Oder mit Betonung auf "so" oder keiner von beiden Wörtern? Die Erklärung, dass "da" einfach nicht zur Konjunktion dazugehört, wie jetzt in mehreren Antworten geschrieben wurde, ist natürlich möglich, aber scheint mir an der Frage vorbeizugehen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zunächst eine Antwort auf die Frage: ja, natürlich kann man "so" als Subjunktion (ähnlich zu "sofern", "falls", "wenn", etc.) verwenden, man muß sich allerdings bewußt sein, daß diese Ausdrucksweise mittlerweile ungewöhnlich ist, was nicht *per se* gegen die Verwendung spricht. Womit, wie von @Janka angemerkt, das Kriterium für "wichtigtuerisch" oder "abgehoben" erfüllt sein sollte, *tut sich mir entziehen*.

Da allerdings in einigen Anworten angemerkt wurde, daß "so da" keine Konjunktion sei, sei hier eine Auflösung angemerkt: das "da" gehört nicht zur Konjunktion, sondern zum Nebensatz und wird analog zu "dort" verwendet:

> Ich ziehe Bad Sowieso als Urlaubsort in Betracht, *so da* [nämlich: dort] ein Thermalbad ist.

Im Falle des Originalsatzes könnte "da" auch für "in dieser Sache/Angelegenheit" stehen, was aber mangels Kontext schwer zu sagen ist.

Answer (score 2):

Gibt es das denn wirklich? Das habe ich mit diesem Sinn noch nicht bewusst gehört und finde es auch in keinen Wörterbüchern. Ich kann die Bedeutung nur aus dem Kontext ableiten. Gibt es irgendwelche Belege aus der Literatur dafür?

"So da" kenne ich nur aus Zusammenhängen, in denen "so" statt eines Relativpronomens genutzt wird:

> Ich besuche gern die Läden in der Schillerstraße, so da sind ein Bäcker, eine Drogerie und ein Delikatessgeschäft.
> Tom und Anne habe drei Kinder, so da heißen Anna, Laura und Benjamin.

DWDS findet:

> Man wird den Dingen, so da kommen sollen, mit Ruhe und Gelassenheit entgegensehen

Bei [49 angezeigten Treffern von "so da" im DWDS-Kernkorpus](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=kern&q=%22so%20da%22) ist keiner dabei, bei dem es so verwendet wird wie in der Frage.

Das gleiche ohne "da" gibt es natürlich ("so" anstelle von "falls"):

> Ich werde dies machen, so die Bedingungen erfüllt sind.

Kann es sein, dass in den Beispiel der Frage einfach "so" statt "falls" benutzt wird, und das "da" eine davon unabhängige Bedeutung im Satz hat?

Benutzen kann man natürlich viel, wenn man die Bedeutung sowieso aus dem Kontext ableiten kann, aber für mich persönlich ist das fremd, und ich bin im Moment noch nicht überzeugt, dass das richtig ist. Für mich also: Nein.

Comment: Für mich liest sich dieses wie ein Kommentar und nicht wie eine Antwort

Answer (score 2):

Eine Konjunktion "so da" ist mir nicht bekannt. Ich denke, dass das "da" zum Nebensatz gehört.

Derselbe Satz in modernerem Deutsch würde *sofern* (oder auch *wenn*) statt *so* benutzen, d.h.:

> Ich werde dies machen, sofern da die Bedingungen erfüllt sind.

Ohne weiteren Kontext lässt sich das allerdings nicht verifizieren.

Die Konjunktion *so* kann heute noch verwendet werden, so es nicht stört, dass der Satz dann ein wenig altertümlich wirkt. ;)

Meist wird *so* als Einleitung eines Nebensatzes allerdings mit *denn* verwendet. Hierzu existiert auch schon eine Frage: [Bedeutung von "so denn überhaupt eine stattfindet"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22544/bedeutung-von-so-denn-%C3%BCberhaupt-eine-stattfindet)

Answer (score 0):

Ja, aber das ist dann schon eine sehr abgehobene, wichtigtuerische Ausdrucksweise. Die weitaus gängigere Alternative ist *sofern*, was auch schon ziemlich selten gesagt sondern hauptsächlich geschrieben wird. Sagen tut man eigentlich immer *wenn*. Nicht einmal *falls*.

Comment: alternativ, aber auch schon etwas stilistisch veraltet, ist einfach nur "so" (statt 'so da' oder 'sofern') zu verwenden.

Comment: Das "da" in dem Satz hat ja mit dem "so" auch nichts zu tun, die stehen nur einfach hintereinander. Das "da" ist hier vermutlich im Sinne von "in dieser Sache" gemeint.